Excel Addin button not showing to external users
I have developed an Excel web addin and it works fine for internal users, but addin buttons are not visible for external users.
I have created a group for both internal and external users. Addin buttons are visible for internal users, but not for external users in the same group.
Please help me find any solution or provide a reference link.

Please clarify what you mean by "internal" and "external" users. Also, how is the add-in deployed? AppSource? Central Deployment?
